# How to increase file upload size in Django application running on EC2 instance with Nginx as revese Proxy?

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn, supervisord

I've a Django application that is running on EC2 instance. It is uploading file upto 100MB without any problems, but above 100MB file size, it gives error **413** **Request Entity Too Large**.

I've tried in file **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** under server configuration.

```
client_max_body_size 10G;
```

I've also applied the same configuration in my domain configuration files, but all in vein. This configuration works well in my other servers, where I am running php applications.

Note: I've used gunicorn with supervisor for running Django application.

Comment: Can you please share your full NGINX configuration? Did you define `client_max_body_size` in both http and https as stated in  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56180132/15353043)?

Comment: Happy to help, I transformed the comment into an answer so you can vote it up :)

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough reputations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `client_max_body_size` has to be defined in both http and https as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36994828/413-request-entity-too-large-nginx-django/56180132#56180132).

So your nginx.conf file under **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** would look something like:

```
http {
    server {
        ...
        listen       80;
        server_name  xxxx.net;
        client_max_body_size 10G;
    }

    server {
        ...
        listen       443 default_server ssl;
        server_name  xxxx.net;
        client_max_body_size 10G;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Helge thanks, I've applied the configuration parameters in both of them.

The issue is resolved now. The issue was, initially it was throwing error due to configuration parameter defined below other parameters, after resolving that Cloudflare started throwing 413 error. So, my team lead made configuration changes for the same.

Answer (score 0):

in you 01__django.config add
files:
"/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
mode: "000755"
owner: root
group: root
content: |
client_max_body_size 20M;
#use These
or go to the your root via ssh
pass the commands

1. cd ..
2. cd ..
   now use :
   sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
   add :
   client_max_body_size 20M; # these will add 20mb of size to your request body
   Now Reload Your NGINX Server
   using nginx -s restart